# In Python, how can I parse YAML with data bindings that don't use YAML tags?

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I am creating a YAML file to hold metadata related to an XML project, and am using Python only as a testing tool -- it is not a python project.

So, I want to write some classes to hold the data, and I'm dismayed to find that the standard way to have PyYAML read my file into these classes automatically is through the use of YAML tags (e.g. `!Monster` to instantiate a Monster object).

I don't want to use tags, because I want these YAML files to be as portable as possible -- readily usable by anyone who wants to, in the language of their choice (as portable as JSON).

It seems to me that the data binding info does not belong inside the YAML file, as a general principle, but after googling for a while, I can't seem to find anyone else complaining about this. I did find a lot of people asking how to parse YAML with unrecognized tags, how to ignore tags, etc. -- so I think I'm right that tags do cause problems for data consumers.

I like the way that [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) works (for parsing JSON in Java) using introspection and annotations. Is there something like that for parsing YAML in Python?

Here's an example of the kind of YAML content I'm talking about:

```
- name: Fleegle
  color: brown
  instruments:
  - path: local/piano
    url: http://example.com/piano
  - path: local/guitar
    url: http://example.com/piano
  songs:
  - name: Blowin in the Wind
    genre: folk
- name: Bingo
  color: red
  instruments:
  - path: local/banjo
    url: http://example.com/banjo
  songs:
  - name: Stairway to Heaven
    year: 1971
```

I'd want to map that to a list of objects of class Split, that has attributes that include an list of Instruments, and a list of Songs.

Comment: Can you post your yaml file content?

Comment: I edited the question with an example of some YAML

Comment: So, this question isn't getting much love -- is it because most folks use YAML simply as a data serialization format, rather than data interchange?

Here's an example of the problem I'm talking about: this online YAML parser chokes, even on one of it's own examples, [example #24 - modified slightly](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=%25TAG+!+tag%3Aclarkevans.com%2C2002%3A%0A---+!shape%0A-+!circle%0A++center%3A+%26ORIGIN+%7Bx%3A+73%2C+y%3A+129%7D%0A++radius%3A+7%0A&type=json)

Comment: I believe the issue you're having with the online YAML parser is specific to that parser. The parser is trying to instantiate a `circle` object from the data, but no `circle` class has been defined in the environment which is evaluating the YAML. It loads fine in Ruby, for example, because Ruby ignores tags that don't have a registered constructor.

Comment: It seems to me that the solution to this is to just write it yourself. Parse the YAML into regular Python objects, then walk the resulting data structure, consuming each object and checking if each key name corresponds to one of your classes and, if it does, passing the data to the constructor.

Comment: Thanks, @Jordan -- yes, that's what I've ended up doing. That's interesting about Ruby. As it stands, I don't even know of a python yaml parser that will be able to ignore tags. I've already written my own ad-hoc one, but I was hoping for a more general solution.

Comment: The answer on this question seems to describe a way to ignore tags (basically defining a constructor that handles all tags and emits a string): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280978/pyyaml-errors-on-in-a-string To ignore tags you would just change it to `return node.value`. I think. Python isn't my bag.

Comment: FWIW Ruby's Psych YAML parser uses libyaml; from the PyYAML README it looks like you can switch to libyaml, and there may be a way to configure it to behave the same way as Psych, but I really don't know.

Comment: How do you expect to know whether `songs` is a list of dictionaries or a list of songs objects? Given that Python does not have static typing... this seems a difficult call. Are you comfortable with coding your own logic for that?

Answer (score 1):

The manual way would be to define something along the following:

```
class Instrument(object):
    def __getstate__(self):
        return {
            "path": self.path,
            "url": self.url,
        }

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.path = state["path"]
        self.url = state["url"]


class Song(object):
    def __getstate__(self):
        return {
            "name": self.name,
            "genre": self.genre,
        }

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.name = state["name"]
        # Note that this can be non-present -> store None
        self.genre = state.get("genre")
        self.year = state.get("year")


class Split(object):
    def __getstate__(self):
        return {
            "name": self.name,
            "color": self.color,
            "instruments": [i.__getstate__() for i in self.instruments],
            "songs": [s.__getstate__() for s in self.songs],
        }

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.name = state["name"]
        self.color = state["color"]
        self.instruments = list()
        for i_state in state["instruments"]:
            i = Instrument.__new__(Instrument)
            i.__setstate__(i_state)
            self.instruments.append(i)

        self.songs = list()
        for s_state in state["songs"]:
            s = Song.__new__(Song)
            s.__setstate__(s_state)
            self.songs.append(s)
```

Note that I am using `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` just to be friendly with `pickle` and some typical applications, but you can use another name for all of that.

Then, assuming that you have the YAML document in a variable named `data` you simply do:

```
structured_data = yaml.load(data)
list_of_splits = list()
for s_state in structured_data:
    s = Split.__new__(Split)
    s.__setstate__(s_state)
    list_of_splits.append(s)
```

The `structured_data` will contain a list of dictionaries of variant stuff. But it all will be plain simple types. The `__setstate__` recursive procedure ensures that everything is what is expected to be --but you must define what is *expected* because we do not have types or any other kind of hint.

---

It could be possible to define some kind of hints in order to automatize this behaviour. I am thinking in something like:

```
class Split(AutoMagicYAMLObject):
    name = StringField()
    color = StringField()
    instruments = ListField(Instrument)
    songs = ListField(Song)
```

... but that would be an interesting application, full of corner cases and delicate design decisions :) I do not know any existing package doing something similar to that, so cannot help more than that.

Comment: I upvoted for the code examles, but your last paragraph neatly summarizes my original question -- that's exactly the kind of thing Jackson does.

Comment: Jackson does it for Java, which has static typing, and thus is a whole different thing (from a programming point of view). So... that is that, this is this :(