# PyYAML: load and dump yaml file and preserve tags ( !CustomTag )

Tags: python, parsing, pyyaml

I want to create a YAML filter that reads a YAML file, processes it and dumps it afterwards.

It must resolve any aliases (that works already nicely out of the box):

```python
>>> yaml.dump(yaml.load("""
Foo: &bar
  name: bar
Foo2:
  <<: *bar
"""))

'Foo: {name: bar}\nFoo2: {name: bar}\n'
```

But it shall also **preserve** any kind of `!CustomTag: foo` expression, like:

```python
>>> yaml.dump(yaml.load("Name: !Foo bar "))
yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: could not determine a constructor for the tag '!Foo' in "<unicode string>", line 1, column 7:
Name: !Foo bar
      ^
```

I read [pyYAML Errors on "!" in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280978/pyyaml-errors-on-in-a-string) and this is close to what I need, except that it parses and outputs the custom tag as **quoted string**, hence it isn't a tag anymore:

```
>>> def default_ctor(loader, tag_suffix, node):
...   return tag_suffix + ' ' + node.value

>>> yaml.add_multi_constructor('', default_ctor)
>>> yaml.dump(yaml.load("Name: !Foo bar "), default_flow_style=False)
"Name: '!Foo bar'\n"
```

I guess there is not much missing, but what? How can I load a file that contains any tags and dump them afterwards?

Comment: Using  `yaml.load()` is unsafe, with that someone can execute arbitrary code if they have control over the YAML file, and PyYAML doesn't warn for its dangers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `default_ctor()` returns a string (which is just a concatenation of the tag and the scalar), that is what is being dumped. And because the tag starts with `!` dumping that string to a scalar will get you quotes.

If you want to generically preserve the tag and value you need to store those in a special type (and not a "normal" Python string) and provide a representer (i.e. dumping routine) for that type:

```
import sys
import yaml

yaml_str = """\
Name: !Foo bar
Alt: !Bar foo
"""


class GenericScalar:
    def __init__(self, value, tag, style=None):
        self._value = value
        self._tag = tag
        self._style = style

    @staticmethod
    def to_yaml(dumper, data):
        # data is a GenericScalar
        return dumper.represent_scalar(data._tag, data._value, style=data._style)


def default_constructor(loader, tag_suffix, node):
    if isinstance(node, yaml.ScalarNode):
        return GenericScalar(node.value, tag_suffix, style=node.style)
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError('Node: ' + str(type(node)))


yaml.add_multi_constructor('', default_constructor, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)

yaml.add_representer(GenericScalar, GenericScalar.to_yaml, Dumper=yaml.SafeDumper)

data = yaml.safe_load(yaml_str)
yaml.safe_dump(data, sys.stdout, default_flow_style=False, allow_unicode=True)
```

This gives:

```
Alt: !Bar 'foo'
Name: !Foo 'bar'
```

Notes:

- It is unsafe to use PyYAML's `load()`. **Don't use it**, it is not necessary (as my code shows). What makes it worse is that there is no feedback from PyYAML that there is any danger.
- PyYAML dumps all scalars that have a tag with quotes, even if you preserve the node style as I do (or force to the empty string). To prevent that from happening you will have to dig pretty deep in the serialisation of nodes. I have been working on a fix for this in my ruamel.yaml package as the quotes are very often not necessary.
- Your anchors and aliases don't get resolved. It is just that PyYAML is not smart enough to do anything but expand the [merge key](http://yaml.org/type/merge.html) at load time. If you have a normal self-reference in your YAML, you'll get an anchor and alias in your dumped YAML.
- The above will nicely raise an error if your node, after the tag, is anything but a scalar (i.e. a mapping or a sequence). It is possible to load/dump those generically as well. by just adding some types and extending the `default_constructor` with some `elif isinstance(node, yaml.MappingNode)` and `elif isinstance(node, yaml.SequenceNode)`. I would make those create different types (that behave like a dict resp. list), and if you go that route you should be aware that constructing those will need to happen in a two-step process (`yield` the constructed object, then get the sub-node values and fill the object), otherwise you cannot use self-referential structures (i.e. aliases within the node).
- PyYAML doesn't preserve the order of the elements in the mapping
- You can have a tag `!CustomTag:` that ends in a colon, but I find it not so human friendly to read `!CustomTag: foo`, as that looks very much like a key-value pair in a block style mapping.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer handles *only* scalars. I need mapping types as well. I wanted a generic solution. I think I may have over-engineered this one.  I feel this could be simpler, and further simplification is welcome.

So if You have Yaml that looks more like this:

```yaml
Name: !Foo bar
Alt: !Bar foo
other: !Join
    - thing
    - other thing
textblock: !Mangle |
    This is a block
    of text that 
    spans lines
```

Try this longer bit of code:

```py
import sys
import yaml
import pprint

yaml_str = """\
Name: !Foo bar
Alt: !Bar foo
other: !Join
    - thing
    - other thing
textblock: !Mangle |
    This is a block
    of text that 
    spans lines
"""

class SafeUnknownConstructor(yaml.constructor.SafeConstructor):
    def __init__(self):
        yaml.constructor.SafeConstructor.__init__(self)

    def construct_undefined(self, node):
        data = getattr(self, 'construct_' + node.id)(node)
        datatype = type(data)
        wraptype = type('TagWrap_'+datatype.__name__, (datatype,), {})
        wrapdata = wraptype(data)
        wrapdata.tag = lambda: None
        wrapdata.datatype = lambda: None
        setattr(wrapdata, "wrapTag", node.tag)
        setattr(wrapdata, "wrapType", datatype)
        return wrapdata


class SafeUnknownLoader(SafeUnknownConstructor, yaml.loader.SafeLoader):

    def __init__(self, stream):
        SafeUnknownConstructor.__init__(self)
        yaml.loader.SafeLoader.__init__(self, stream)


class SafeUnknownRepresenter(yaml.representer.SafeRepresenter):
    def represent_data(self, wrapdata):
        tag = False
        if type(wrapdata).__name__.startswith('TagWrap_'):
            datatype = getattr(wrapdata, "wrapType")
            tag = getattr(wrapdata, "wrapTag")
            data = datatype(wrapdata)
        else:
            data = wrapdata
        node = super(SafeUnknownRepresenter, self).represent_data(data)
        if tag:
            node.tag = tag
        return node

class SafeUnknownDumper(SafeUnknownRepresenter, yaml.dumper.SafeDumper):

    def __init__(self, stream,
            default_style=None, default_flow_style=False,
            canonical=None, indent=None, width=None,
            allow_unicode=None, line_break=None,
            encoding=None, explicit_start=None, explicit_end=None,
            version=None, tags=None, sort_keys=True):

        SafeUnknownRepresenter.__init__(self, default_style=default_style,
                default_flow_style=default_flow_style, sort_keys=sort_keys)

        yaml.dumper.SafeDumper.__init__(self,  stream,
                                        default_style=default_style,
                                        default_flow_style=default_flow_style,
                                        canonical=canonical,
                                        indent=indent,
                                        width=width,
                                        allow_unicode=allow_unicode,
                                        line_break=line_break,
                                        encoding=encoding,
                                        explicit_start=explicit_start,
                                        explicit_end=explicit_end,
                                        version=version,
                                        tags=tags,
                                        sort_keys=sort_keys)


MySafeLoader = SafeUnknownLoader
yaml.constructor.SafeConstructor.add_constructor(None, SafeUnknownConstructor.construct_undefined)
data = yaml.load(yaml_str, MySafeLoader)
pprint.pprint(data)
yaml.dump_all([data], sys.stdout, Dumper=SafeUnknownDumper, default_flow_style=False, allow_unicode=True)
```

Which outputs:

```
{'Alt': u'foo',
 'Name': u'bar',
 'other': ['thing', 'other thing'],
 'textblock': u'This is a block\nof text that \nspans lines\n'}

Alt: !Bar 'foo'
Name: !Foo 'bar'
other: !Join
- thing
- other thing
textblock: !Mangle "This is a block\nof text that \nspans lines\n"
```

Note: If added code updates the data and doesn't check for the wrapper it can revert elements to the unwrapped type and lose the tag