# Python - preserving custom YAML tags when loading and dumping

Tags: python, yaml

I am attempting to write code that can load a YAML file (or string) that contains a custom tag, modify the yaml data, and then dump the yaml data preserving the tags. Following the advice found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/43768117/8497610, I have written the following:

```
import yaml
import sys

class GenericMapping:
    def __init__(self, value, tag, style=None):
        self._value = value
        self._tag = tag

    @staticmethod
    def to_yaml(dumper, data):
        # data is a GenericMapping
        return dumper.represent_mapping(data._tag, data._value)


class GenericScalar:
    def __init__(self, value, tag, style=None):
        self._value = value
        self._tag = tag
        self._style = style

    @staticmethod
    def to_yaml(dumper, data):
        # data is a GenericScalar
        return dumper.represent_scalar(data._tag, data._value, style=data._style)


def default_constructor(loader, tag_suffix, node):
    if isinstance(node, yaml.MappingNode):
        return GenericMapping(node.value, tag_suffix)
    if isinstance(node, yaml.ScalarNode):
        return GenericScalar(node.value, tag_suffix, style=node.style)
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError('Node: ' + str(type(node)))

yaml.add_multi_constructor('', default_constructor, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)

yaml.add_representer(GenericScalar, GenericScalar.to_yaml, Dumper=yaml.SafeDumper)
yaml.add_representer(GenericMapping, GenericMapping.to_yaml, Dumper=yaml.SafeDumper)


yaml_str = """\
  my_var: !mytag
    sub_var: 1
    sub_var: 2
"""

data = yaml.safe_load(yaml_str)
yaml.safe_dump(data, sys.stdout, default_flow_style=False, allow_unicode=True)
```

However, I am obtaining the following error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "modify_yamls.py", line 48,
> in <module>
>     yaml.safe_dump(data, sys.stdout, default_flow_style=False, allow_unicode=True)   File
> "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 216, in
> safe_dump
>     return dump_all([data], stream, Dumper=SafeDumper, **kwds)   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 188, in
> dump_all
>     dumper.represent(data)   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/representer.py", line 26, in
> represent
>     node = self.represent_data(data)   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/representer.py", line 47, in
> represent_data
>     node = self.yaml_representers[data_types[0]](self, data)   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/representer.py", line 205, in
> represent_dict
>     return self.represent_mapping('tag:yaml.org,2002:map', data)   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/representer.py", line
> 116, in represent_mapping
>     node_value = self.represent_data(item_value)   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/representer.py", line 47, in
> represent_data
>     node = self.yaml_representers[data_types[0]](self, data)   File "modify_yamls.py", line 12, in to_yaml
>     return dumper.represent_mapping(data._tag, data._value)   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/representer.py", line 115, in
> represent_mapping
>     node_key = self.represent_data(item_key)   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/representer.py", line 57, in
> represent_data
>     node = self.yaml_representers[None](self, data)   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/representer.py", line 229, in
> represent_undefined
>     raise RepresenterError("cannot represent an object: %s" % data) yaml.representer.RepresenterError: cannot represent an object:
> ScalarNode(tag='tag:yaml.org,2002:str', value='sub_var'
```

Any ideas where I went wrong with my representers?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC the advice I gave in the answer you link to, was for adding a custom tag to an existing data structure. Apart
from that the answer uses PyYAML which was already outdated in 2017 (by not supporting YAML 1.2, introduced in 2009).

Your YAML input is invalid, as (even in YAML 1.1) you are not allowed to have non-unique **keys** in a mapping, but because of a longstanding bug in PyYAML, this is ignored when loading.

This kind of round-tripping is best done with my `ruamel.yaml` package which can handle tags (except for tagged `nil` values), without any special coding:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
my_var: !mytag
  sub_var_a: 1
  sub_var_b: 2
"""
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
data['my_var']['sub_var_b'] = 6
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
my_var: !mytag
  sub_var_a: 1
  sub_var_b: 6
```