# !!python/str doesn't work for RasaCore's domain.yml

Tags: python, yaml

I am studying Rasa and I'm having some problem with running the dialog model.

```
python3 -m rasa_core.train -s data/stories.md -d domain.yml -o models/dialogue --epochs 300
```

## Error!

```
ruamel.yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: could not determine a constructor for the tag 'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/str'
in "/my/app/path/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rasa_core/schemas/domain.yml", line 4, column 11
```

### Rasa Core

Upon looking at the domain.yml from rasa_core, it seems that the problem is with double exclamation marks `!!`

#### domain.yml

```
allowempty: True
mapping:
  intents:
    type: !!python/str "seq"
```

Read, another post about double exclamation marks from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280978/pyyaml-errors-on-in-a-string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying arbitrary things, you should think about what you want to do. `!!python/str` is a tag denoting the Python string type. So your current YAML says „`seq` is a Python string`“.

Now your change would instead say „load the following value as whatever type you think is appropriate: `!!python/str seq`“. That is a very different thing.

Let's figure out why ruamel does not recognize your tag. [A quick look in the source](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml/src/397b425c3bb441451b25669a7d3fdf6b8ff93701/constructor.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#constructor.py-892) reveals that `!!python/str` is registered in the standard `Constructor`, but not in the `SafeConstructor`. That only has YAML's standard tag [!!str](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml/src/397b425c3bb441451b25669a7d3fdf6b8ff93701/constructor.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#constructor.py-670) available. So chances are that you are using the `SafeConstructor` which simply does not know about `!!python/str`. So a possible fix would be to use `!!str` instead which calls the same constructor on the scalar (as we see in the source).

Alternatively, you could just drop the tag. the scalar `seq` would be loaded into a string anyway unless RasaCore does something unexpected (I actually do not know anything about that).

Comment: thank you flyx for your comprehensive reply. it did work using your solution